# Parallelizing Lime in data bricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, parallel-processing, lime

I am trying to parallelize lime framework on databricks , but not able to do so.
I dont know how , how can i send every observation on different workers,  if anyone could help.

Ex plainer is coming from the lime framework.

Code below :

```
 import lime 
 import lime.lime_tabular   
 explainer=
 lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(X_train,feature_names=train_columns,
        class_names=['look_forward_Repatha'],verbose=True,
                                               mode='regression')
 --------------------------------
def calculate_in_parallel(line):
  test_nparray = np.array(line)
  exp = explainer.explain_instance(test_nparray,xgb_model.predict, 
  num_features=30)
  return exp.as_list()

test_rdd = sc.parallelize(df_pred_X_test_skew_nohighcoll.values)
test_rdd = test_rdd.map(calculate_in_parallel)
test_rdd = test_rdd.collect()
```